# Unable to call the SharePoint Custom web service from another SharePoint Farm

Tags: asp.net, web-services, sharepoint

I have deployed a custom SharePoint Web service on Farm A. I am trying to access this Web service from a SharePoint timer job on Farm B. On Farm B, I am creating Class Library project, packaging it (wsp) and then deploying to GAC. The problem is I'm unable to access the Web Service using the following code. `TodaysNewSVC` is a service reference

```
      TodaysNewSVC.GetTodaysnewsfromInsite objGetNews = new TodaysNewSVC.GetTodaysnewsfromInsite();
      objGetNews.PreAuthenticate = true;
      objGetNews.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
      objGetNews.Url = "http://insite-dev.portal/_vti_bin/todaysnews.asmx";
      DataTable dt2 = objGetNews.getNewsFromInsite(true, true);

//getNewsFromInsite is a WebMethod which returns the DataTable.
```

**Note**: Both farms use the same active directory authentication. I have also done the debugging for Timer Job and feature activation and they are working fine. The problem occurs during the call i.e.  `getNewsFromInsite`

The asmx and wsdl files are accessible from Internet Explorer and also from Windows Console application. Here is the code which I use from console application:

```
            GetTodaysnewsfromInsiteSoapClient objWSClient = new GetTodaysnewsfromInsiteSoapClient();
            objWSClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            objWSClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
            DataTable dt = objWSClient.getNewsFromInsite(true, true);
```

**Here is the error message:**

```
The request failed with the error message:
--
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="%2fPages%2fproblem-with-page.aspx%3fc%3d500">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `problem-with-page.aspx` ? Is it a login or a custom error page ?

If its login page, then your authentication is failing. I doubt if its login page because you mentioned Active Directory authentication.

If its custom error page, the target code is throwing the exception. Are you able to step in to the target code ?

Comment: Yes Madhur, I'm unable to authenticate and I'm using integrated windows authentication. I have checked the directory _vti_bin of 12 hive is set anonymous with integrated windows authentication. its MOSS 2007. BTW, I'm calling this web service from another farm and unable to step into the target code!